# Don't understand the syntax for accessing JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I simply do not understand the syntax for accessing JSON data in PHP. I've been fiddling about with this for awhile . I'm too javascript-ish to understand.

```
$patchData = $_POST['mydata'];
$encoded = json_encode($patchData,true);
$patchDataJSON = json_decode($encoded,true);


/* what my JSON object looks like

{"patch_name":"whatever","sound_type":{

 "synths":[
    {"synth_name":"synth1","xpos":"29.99999725818634","ypos":"10.000012516975403"},
    {"synth_name":"synth2","xpos":"1.999997252328634","ypos":"18.000012516975403"},

    ]
  }
} 

*/


$patchName = $patchDataJSON['patch_name'];  // works!
$soundType = $patchDataJSON['sound_type']; // trying to access innards of JSON object. Does not work

echo $soundType;   // Does not work.
```

Comment: `var_dump($soundType);`

Comment: $soundType is an object, try with $soundType['synths']['synth_name']

Comment: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($patchDataJSON, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: @sensorario According to `json_encode(..., true)`, it should be an associative array.

Comment: `json_encode(..., true)` returns a string, What the true is there for I don't know. I suspect someone's confused encode with decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` returns a nested PHP array corresponding to the JSON structure. (When passed `true` as second parameter, otherwise it returns PHP objects).

To print it, use `var_dump` or `print_r`:

```
$soundType = $patchDataJSON['sound_type'];
print_r($soundType);
```

To access the fields, use string or numerical indices (depending on the input JSON):

```
$xpos = $soundType['synths'][0]['xpos'];
```

Etc.

A simple example:

```
$jsonString = '{"foo": "bar", "baz": [{"val": 5}]}';
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
print_r($decoded);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [baz] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [val] => 5
                )
        )
)
```